# Replacing Part of a String without Replace/Stuff

Tags: sql-server, string, replace

This is my string: 11.0000.0101.000.000.0101.000.000

I need to replace ONLY the first "0101" with "101." I can't use replace, as it replaces the 2nd instance of 0101 as well.

I tried

```
stuff(string, 9, 3, '101')
```

but since the replacement string is shorter than the existing string, I end up with

11.0000.1011.000.000.0101.000.000

What can I use besides REPLACE or STUFF? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    declare @t table(s varchar(100))
    insert into  @t values
    ( '11.0000.0101.000.000.0101.000.000'), ('abc');

    select case charindex('0101', s) 
                when 0 then s
                else stuff(s, charindex('0101', s), 4, '101')
           end as new_s      
    from @t;
```

Comment: I was going here. You beat me to it. The answer above assumes you have a static string.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression was almost right.

Just tell it to replace 4 characters of the original string instead of 3 :

```
stuff(string, 9, 4, '101')
```

But this will only work if your string has always the same positions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
replace (stuff(string,9,3,'#101'),'#','')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need replace all 0101 to 101 go with below code

```
 DECLARE @TempData TABLE(Data VARCHAR(1000));
    INSERT INTO @TempData VALUES
        ('11.0000.0101.000.000.0101.000.000');

    ;WITH Cte
    AS (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN DATA = '0101'
                    THEN '101'
                ELSE CAST(DATA AS VARCHAR(10))
                END AS DATA
        FROM (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Data
            FROM (
                SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Data, '.', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Data
                FROM @TempData
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
            ) Dt
        )
    SELECT STUFF((
                SELECT '.' + DATA
                FROM cte
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS ExpectedResult
```

OutPut

```
ExpectedResult
11.0000.101.000.000.101.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option if you don't know the 1st observation

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = '11.0000.0101.000.000.0101.000.000'
Declare @Find varchar(25) = '0101'
Declare @Repl varchar(25) = '101'


Select isnull(stuff(@S, charindex(@Find,@S), len(@Find), @Repl),@S)
```

Returns

```
11.0000.101.000.000.0101.000.000
```